# Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Tags: java, android

I don't know what to do about the following errors, I've searched the web but not found anything:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.padmw-CXElJ_vfrfm3y7py3CPsJw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

and :

```
2019-08-29 00:19:24.071 1853-1853/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.padmw-CXElJ_vfrfm3y7py3CPsJw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

my dependencies in gradle app :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After migration to AndroidX, exception at start up: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "Didn't find class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252142/after-migration-to-androidx-exception-at-start-up-java-lang-classnotfoundexcep)

Comment: Probably it happened after upgrade of some libraries (added JUnit and updated Firebase), but after recompilation it disappeared.

Comment: A picture is worth of 1000 words---Here are the details solution works in my case maybe yours too-- [Before error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDEoZ.png) [After fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7F0p.png)

Answer (score 43):

Adding Java 1.8 compatibility to my module-level `build.gradle` fixed this for me (non-release build with multidex enabled).

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure why :)

Comment: This worked for me. For more info, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561908

Comment: project- or app-level `build.gradle`?

Comment: Module level @Ben

Answer (score 21):

This error message is caused on API level 28+ by:
[`AppComponentFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/AppComponentFactory) `extends` [`android.app.AppComponentFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppComponentFactory.html)

This means that on API 28+ one can use `tools:remove` ...

```
<application ... 
tools:remove="android:appComponentFactory"
tools:targetApi="p" >
```

Comment: Just adding the first line in the Manifest file did it for me.

Comment: What node in the Manifest file do we add `tools:remove` to?

Comment: Think this was the `application` node.

Comment: Thank you, adding it to the <application> node solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the code works on one of my teammates' machine. 
These steps made it work for me too:

1. Close project
2. Remove the project from the list in the welcome screen
3. Open the project again

This is a solution to another problem, that I also found here in SO. It's worth a try when **Invalidate and Restart** doesn't solve it for you.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe that solved my problem.  It's also solved the problem of the debugger disconnecting a second after it hit a breakpoint.

Answer (score 4):

It may sound totally unrelated, but I have seen this problem also when by mistake I have overridden wrong on Activity#onCreate() method
i.e.

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState,
        @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

Instead of

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

So, please check that also.
The second one is the one that you probably need.

Please refer to documentation for the details of these two methods.

Comment: It seems to have been the answer of @Tomasz but then I add to `File > Sync Project with Gradle Files` to get it working. For interested ones, I found `Sync project with Gradle before building, if needed` in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug, check the next link in the issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137646829

Comment: This can occur with non-release builds as well so it's not the whole story

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an emulator, try the wipe data option. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

See [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.my_app_name.androidx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438312/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-com-my-app-name-androidx).

Remove from `AndroidManifest`:

```
<application
    ...
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
>
```

These lines appeared a year ago after migrating to AndroidX. I removed them, now it doesn't show the exception.

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin folks running into this problem: I started to see this problem when upgrading from Xamarin.Forms 4.x to 5.0. With AndroidX changes that I wasn't aware when I've done the upgrade the min SDK version needs to be changed to 29 on the android manifest file, something like:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />`

Answer (score 1):

**For anyone facing the same problem in the multi-Module project:->**
*In my case I had a multi-module project using the Jetpack compose for the presentation layer*

1. Just Clean the project
2. Rebuild it
3. Then again run the project

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a library that has an interface that was inheriting a View.OnClickListener interface.

Comment: Could you expand on why this is relevant? I think it would be quite common for classes to inherit View.OnClickListener - if so, is there a work around without having to stop inheriting this class?

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused due to using both `androidx` and `legacy` android support libraries

Just open `project structure` and go to Dependencies and select `All Modules` and check is there any library which contains `android.support`

Just replace that with `androidx` version for that `library`

In the latest versions of android studio, just REMOVE these lines if it is there inside the manifest file

```
<application
...
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"  // REMOVE THIS
android:appComponentFactory="androidx"       // REMOVE THIS
>
```

If still there is issue check this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74523286/6236959

Answer (score 0):

in my case @AndroidEntryPoint was missing

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar `Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"` issue using dynamic feature modules (SplitInstallManagerFactory) on a newer project.

The issue occurred during the install of dynamic feature modules only when obfuscation was enabled (i.e., `isMinifyEnabled = true`). This keep rule fixed it when added to my base app module's `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory { *; }
```

Tom's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59296304/11321246) of falling back to java 1.8 also resolved the issue for me, but this keep rule allowed me to stay on the java 17 LTS.

Looking into the android/openjdk source, the `BaseDexClassLoader.findClass` function appears to be inherited from `java.lang.ClassLoader`. This deals with classes as strings, so my best guess is that R8 was obfuscating the androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory class. I can't guess as to why falling back to java 1.8 would also resolve the issue.

Answer (score -2):

In my case ,that was because of a little mistake in one of my layouts.

I removed one `>` at the end of a view tag accidentlly.

Check your

> xml

files.

Answer (score -2):

<s>After reviewing the Android Issue Tracker bug report mentioned previously, I saw a mention about multidex support. I had no multidex flags specified in my project, so I tried setting the flag to `false` on all modules in my project, and the exception went away.</s>

This was not a permanent solution; the problem returned a few builds later.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to set multidex to true because of my app size.

Answer (score -3):

add below code to `gradle.properties`

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

or you can choose migrate to androidX in refactor -> Migrate to androidX.

Answer (score -3):

In my case, add `android.enableR8=false` in the gradle.properties.

Comment: Thank you, my issue is solved after adding this line

Comment: @MohamedHussien it's not good solution, your turn off obfuscation

Answer (score -7):

did u create fragments?
ok if you create fragments with classes and after that you have to create a class to call those fragments.  and if you use switch this cane be like this

`public Fragment getItem(int i) {

```
    // you have create a switch to get positions using i.
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
            return chatsFragment;

        case 1:
            GroupsFragment groupsFragment = new GroupsFragment();
            return groupsFragment;

        case 2:
            ContactsFragment contactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
            return contactsFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;//error can be happen if u use default 0, use fragment counts in here.
}`
```

in this case you can see 3 cases in **switch**
and the **public int getCount()** the return value should be **3**  *not default value 0*.

See your error must be close to this one. i got same kind of error and i solved it.