# Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory or Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, firebase, performance, android-studio

Everything is good don't know why getting this error !!

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.3'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'

}
```

i tried everything but not finding solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory)