# app crashes after launch when trying to set up firestore in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I learning android app development and was trying to set up firestore, I followed all the steps but when I launched the app it crashed and I can't figure it out what's the problem.

I have cross checked my gradle and everything seems to be fine.
here is my gradle module app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firestoreexample"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

I have also checked my gradle project and in this also everything seems to be fine.
here is my gradle project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Everytime when I launch my app this error message shows up and I cant figure out what's the issue.
Here is the Error message:

```
E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:731)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
                ... 12 more
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firestoreexample, PID: 22749
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:121)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6380)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.firestoreexample-iOmZ-M_N_z-WXZzYWD0fxA==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
                ... 8 more
```

Need help as I am struggling with it even after watching so many videos and that's depressing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be missing

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
```

Try replacing the version with the newest one.

If that doesn't help, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory)

Comment: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0' is not helping either and the thread is also not helpful because that seems to be kotlin and not java