# Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

Actually, I was working on one project and to test the implemented feature, I have build the project but unfortunately, i have got the error like: "Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory" .

I didn't change any kind of gradle or manifest related changes. Just restructure gson response model based restructured API and based on that model, I have also modified some model mapping. and for API calling, I am using retrofit.

I have just added Hilt dependency into app level gradle and did some required changes into the project level gradle as per google documentation.

Here, I want to understand the root of this error.

Thank you in advance!

Here is the error response which i am facing!

```
Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.<ProjectName>.app-uNyluFOJTyG6uVYYO-7V6w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.<ProjectName>.app-uNyluFOJTyG6uVYYO-7V6w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
```

I have tried many things which are mentioned into one stackOverflow Question.

[Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory)

Also, refer some other asked Questions related to the same from the StackOverflow as well as from other sources, but not getting any solution!

But, not a single answer worked for me.

Comment: Would you be able to share a link to sample app project? I will be able to check it  out at my end.

Comment: Hello Hardik, Due to the NDA with client, I can't share the actual project and i don't know that how this error is going to reproduce. So, I can't create saperate sample project for the same!

I am sincerely apologize for that.

Comment: That's fine Alex. This kind of errors are nightmares for us devs.

Comment: Yes.. Exactly!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700486/didnt-find-class-androidx-core-app-corecomponentfactory)

Comment: No.., I have tried all these solutions but no one are working for me.

Comment: Interesting thing is like I have faced same error 3rd time but this time those solutions don't work for me! as well as in my prev project, i had fixed this error by using bellow given answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my past,
I had faced same issue and resolved by changing the following things into gradle.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:x.x.x'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:x.x.x'
```

and have enabled multidex enabled into build.gradle file in defaultConfig section like:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of unexpected errors, you can clean and rebuild the project. It works in this kind of unexpected error.

Also, you can also invalidate caches and restart the Android studio.

Sometimes, these both are common solutions for this kind of error!
However, I also don't know the root of this error but the above solutions work for me.